# Tailwind opacity not applied to overriden colors

Tags: tailwind-css

I have tailwind-preset.js file where I'm defining overriden and extended values according to _variables.css file generated from Figma design tokens. When using any of the colors in the code, for example, `bg-orange-500 bg-opacity-40`, opacity is not being applied to the color.

Here is how tailwind-preset.js file looks like:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        colors: {
            white: 'var(--colors-default-white)',
            black: 'var(--colors-default-black)',
            transparent: 'var(--colors-default-transparent)',
            gray: {
                50: 'var(--colors-default-gray-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-default-gray-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-default-gray-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-default-gray-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-default-gray-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-default-gray-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-default-gray-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-default-gray-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-default-gray-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-default-gray-900)',
            },
            slate: {
                50: 'var(--colors-slate-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-slate-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-slate-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-slate-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-slate-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-slate-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-slate-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-slate-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-slate-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-slate-900)',
            },
            gray: {
                50: 'var(--colors-gray-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-gray-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-gray-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-gray-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-gray-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-gray-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-gray-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-gray-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-gray-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-gray-900)',
            },
            zinc: {
                50: 'var(--colors-zinc-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-zinc-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-zinc-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-zinc-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-zinc-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-zinc-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-zinc-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-zinc-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-zinc-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-zinc-900)',
            },
            neutral: {
                50: 'var(--colors-neutral-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-neutral-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-neutral-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-neutral-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-neutral-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-neutral-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-neutral-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-neutral-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-neutral-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-neutral-900)',
            },
            stone: {
                50: 'var(--colors-stone-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-stone-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-stone-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-stone-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-stone-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-stone-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-stone-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-stone-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-stone-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-stone-900)',
            },
            red: {
                50: 'var(--colors-red-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-red-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-red-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-red-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-red-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-red-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-red-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-red-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-red-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-red-900)',
            },
            orange: {
                50: 'var(--colors-orange-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-orange-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-orange-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-orange-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-orange-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-orange-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-orange-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-orange-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-orange-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-orange-900)',
            },
            amber: {
                50: 'var(--colors-amber-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-amber-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-amber-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-amber-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-amber-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-amber-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-amber-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-amber-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-amber-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-amber-900)',
            },
            yellow: {
                50: 'var(--colors-yellow-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-yellow-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-yellow-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-yellow-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-yellow-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-yellow-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-yellow-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-yellow-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-yellow-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-yellow-900)',
            },
            lime: {
                50: 'var(--colors-lime-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-lime-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-lime-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-lime-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-lime-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-lime-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-lime-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-lime-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-lime-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-lime-900)',
            },
            green: {
                50: 'var(--colors-green-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-green-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-green-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-green-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-green-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-green-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-green-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-green-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-green-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-green-900)',
            },
            emerald: {
                50: 'var(--colors-emerald-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-emerald-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-emerald-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-emerald-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-emerald-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-emerald-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-emerald-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-emerald-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-emerald-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-emerald-900)',
            },
            teal: {
                50: 'var(--colors-teal-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-teal-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-teal-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-teal-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-teal-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-teal-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-teal-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-teal-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-teal-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-teal-900)',
            },
            cyan: {
                50: 'var(--colors-cyan-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-cyan-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-cyan-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-cyan-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-cyan-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-cyan-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-cyan-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-cyan-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-cyan-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-cyan-900)',
            },
            sky: {
                50: 'var(--colors-sky-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-sky-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-sky-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-sky-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-sky-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-sky-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-sky-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-sky-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-sky-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-sky-900)',
            },
            blue: {
                50: 'var(--colors-blue-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-blue-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-blue-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-blue-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-blue-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-blue-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-blue-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-blue-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-blue-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-blue-900)',
            },
            indigo: {
                50: 'var(--colors-indigo-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-indigo-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-indigo-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-indigo-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-indigo-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-indigo-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-indigo-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-indigo-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-indigo-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-indigo-900)',
            },
            violet: {
                50: 'var(--colors-violet-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-violet-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-violet-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-violet-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-violet-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-violet-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-violet-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-violet-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-violet-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-violet-900)',
            },
            purple: {
                50: 'var(--colors-purple-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-purple-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-purple-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-purple-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-purple-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-purple-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-purple-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-purple-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-purple-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-purple-900)',
            },
            fuchsia: {
                50: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-fuchsia-900)',
            },
            pink: {
                50: 'var(--colors-pink-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-pink-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-pink-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-pink-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-pink-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-pink-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-pink-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-pink-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-pink-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-pink-900)',
            },
            rose: {
                50: 'var(--colors-rose-50)',
                100: 'var(--colors-rose-100)',
                200: 'var(--colors-rose-200)',
                300: 'var(--colors-rose-300)',
                400: 'var(--colors-rose-400)',
                500: 'var(--colors-rose-500)',
                600: 'var(--colors-rose-600)',
                700: 'var(--colors-rose-700)',
                800: 'var(--colors-rose-800)',
                900: 'var(--colors-rose-900)',
            },
        },
        opacity: {
            0: 'var(--opacity-0)',
            5: 'var(--opacity-5)',
            10: 'var(--opacity-10)',
            15: 'var(--opacity-15)',
            20: 'var(--opacity-20)',
            25: 'var(--opacity-25)',
            30: 'var(--opacity-30)',
            35: 'var(--opacity-35)',
            40: 'var(--opacity-40)',
            50: 'var(--opacity-50)',
            60: 'var(--opacity-60)',
            70: 'var(--opacity-70)',
            75: 'var(--opacity-75)',
            80: 'var(--opacity-80)',
            90: 'var(--opacity-90)',
            95: 'var(--opacity-95)',
            100: 'var(--opacity-100)',
        },
        ...
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: {
                'primary-gradient': 'var(--primary-gradient)',
                'primary-gradient-reverse': 'var(--primary-gradient-reverse)',
                'background-gradient': 'var(--background-gradient)',
            },
            fontFamily: {
                'lacavf': ['lacavf-extralight', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
                'lora': ['lora'],
            },
            margin: {
                'pageTop': 'var(--global-page-top)',
                'xlPageTop': 'var(--global-page-top-xl)',
                'pageLeft': 'var(--global-page-left)',
                'pageRight': 'var(--global-page-right)',
            },
            keyframes: {
                pulse2: {
                    '0%, 100%': {opacity: '1'},
                    '50%': {opacity: '0'},
                }
            },
            animation: {
                pulse2: 'pulse2 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) infinite',
            }
            ...
        }
    },
    screens: {
        'sm': 'var(--screens-sm)',
        'md': 'var(--screens-md)',
        'lg': 'var(--screens-lg)',
        'xl': 'var(--screens-xl)',
        '2xl': 'var(--screens-2xl)',
    },
    plugins: [
        function ({ addUtilities }) {
            addUtilities({
                '.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar': {
                    width: '0.5em',
                },
                '.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
                '.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                },
            });
        },
    ],
};
```

Here is how _variables.css file looks like:

```
/**
 * Do not edit directly
 * Generated on Sun, 14 Jan 2024 10:17:53 GMT
 */

:root {
  --colors-default-white: #ffffff;
  --colors-default-black: #000000;
  --colors-default-transparent: transparent;
  --colors-default-gray-50: #f9fafb;
  --colors-default-gray-100: #f3f4f6;
  --colors-default-gray-200: #e5e7eb;
  --colors-default-gray-300: #d1d5db;
  --colors-default-gray-400: #9ca3af;
  --colors-default-gray-500: #6b7280;
  --colors-default-gray-600: #4b5563;
  --colors-default-gray-700: #374151;
  --colors-default-gray-800: #1f2937;
  --colors-default-gray-900: #111827;
  --colors-slate-50: #f8fafc;
  --colors-slate-100: #f1f5f9;
  --colors-slate-200: #e2e8f0;
  --colors-slate-300: #cbd5e1;
  --colors-slate-400: #94a3b8;
  --colors-slate-500: #64748b;
  --colors-slate-600: #475569;
  --colors-slate-700: #334155;
  --colors-slate-800: #1e293b;
  --colors-slate-900: #0f172a;
  --colors-gray-50: #f9fafb;
  --colors-gray-100: #f3f4f6;
  --colors-gray-200: #e5e7eb;
  --colors-gray-300: #d1d5db;
  --colors-gray-400: #9ca3af;
  --colors-gray-500: #6b7280;
  --colors-gray-600: #4b5563;
  --colors-gray-700: #374151;
  --colors-gray-800: #1f2937;
  --colors-gray-900: #111827;
  --colors-zinc-50: #fafafa;
  --colors-zinc-100: #f4f4f5;
  --colors-zinc-200: #e4e4e7;
  --colors-zinc-300: #d4d4d8;
  --colors-zinc-400: #a1a1aa;
  --colors-zinc-500: #71717a;
  --colors-zinc-600: #52525b;
  --colors-zinc-700: #3f3f46;
  --colors-zinc-800: #27272a;
  --colors-zinc-900: #18181b;
  --colors-neutral-50: #fafafa;
  --colors-neutral-100: #f5f5f5;
  --colors-neutral-200: #e5e5e5;
  --colors-neutral-300: #d4d4d4;
  --colors-neutral-400: #a3a3a3;
  --colors-neutral-500: #737373;
  --colors-neutral-600: #525252;
  --colors-neutral-700: #404040;
  --colors-neutral-800: #262626;
  --colors-neutral-900: #171717;
  --colors-stone-50: #fafaf9;
  --colors-stone-100: #f5f5f4;
  --colors-stone-200: #e7e5e4;
  --colors-stone-300: #d6d3d1;
  --colors-stone-400: #a8a29e;
  --colors-stone-500: #78716c;
  --colors-stone-600: #57534e;
  --colors-stone-700: #44403c;
  --colors-stone-800: #292524;
  --colors-stone-900: #1c1917;
  --colors-red-50: #fef2f2;
  --colors-red-100: #fee2e2;
  --colors-red-200: #fecaca;
  --colors-red-300: #fca5a5;
  --colors-red-400: #f87171;
  --colors-red-500: #ef4444;
  --colors-red-600: #dc2626;
  --colors-red-700: #b91c1c;
  --colors-red-800: #991b1b;
  --colors-red-900: #7f1d1d;
  --colors-orange-50: #fff7ed;
  --colors-orange-100: #ffedd5;
  --colors-orange-200: #fed7aa;
  --colors-orange-300: #fdba74;
  --colors-orange-400: #fb923c;
  --colors-orange-500: #f97316;
  --colors-orange-600: #ea580c;
  --colors-orange-700: #c2410c;
  --colors-orange-800: #9a3412;
  --colors-orange-900: #7c2d12;
  --colors-amber-50: #fffbeb;
  --colors-amber-100: #fef3c7;
  --colors-amber-200: #fde68a;
  --colors-amber-300: #fcd34d;
  --colors-amber-400: #fbbf24;
  --colors-amber-500: #f59e0b;
  --colors-amber-600: #d97706;
  --colors-amber-700: #b45309;
  --colors-amber-800: #92400e;
  --colors-amber-900: #78350f;
  --colors-yellow-50: #fefce8;
  --colors-yellow-100: #fef9c3;
  --colors-yellow-200: #fef08a;
  --colors-yellow-300: #fde047;
  --colors-yellow-400: #facc15;
  --colors-yellow-500: #eab308;
  --colors-yellow-600: #ca8a04;
  --colors-yellow-700: #a16207;
  --colors-yellow-800: #854d0e;
  --colors-yellow-900: #713f12;
  --colors-lime-50: #f7fee7;
  --colors-lime-100: #ecfccb;
  --colors-lime-200: #d9f99d;
  --colors-lime-300: #bef264;
  --colors-lime-400: #a3e635;
  --colors-lime-500: #84cc16;
  --colors-lime-600: #65a30d;
  --colors-lime-700: #4d7c0f;
  --colors-lime-800: #3f6212;
  --colors-lime-900: #365314;
  --colors-green-50: #f0fdf4;
  --colors-green-100: #dcfce7;
  --colors-green-200: #bbf7d0;
  --colors-green-300: #86efac;
  --colors-green-400: #4ade80;
  --colors-green-500: #22c55e;
  --colors-green-600: #16a34a;
  --colors-green-700: #15803d;
  --colors-green-800: #166534;
  --colors-green-900: #14532d;
  --colors-emerald-50: #ecfdf5;
  --colors-emerald-100: #d1fae5;
  --colors-emerald-200: #a7f3d0;
  --colors-emerald-300: #6ee7b7;
  --colors-emerald-400: #34d399;
  --colors-emerald-500: #10b981;
  --colors-emerald-600: #059669;
  --colors-emerald-700: #047857;
  --colors-emerald-800: #065f46;
  --colors-emerald-900: #064e3b;
  --colors-teal-50: #f0fdfa;
  --colors-teal-100: #ccfbf1;
  --colors-teal-200: #99f6e4;
  --colors-teal-300: #5eead4;
  --colors-teal-400: #2dd4bf;
  --colors-teal-500: #14b8a6;
  --colors-teal-600: #0d9488;
  --colors-teal-700: #0f766e;
  --colors-teal-800: #115e59;
  --colors-teal-900: #134e4a;
  --colors-cyan-50: #ecfeff;
  --colors-cyan-100: #cffafe;
  --colors-cyan-200: #a5f3fc;
  --colors-cyan-300: #67e8f9;
  --colors-cyan-400: #22d3ee;
  --colors-cyan-500: #06b6d4;
  --colors-cyan-600: #0891b2;
  --colors-cyan-700: #0e7490;
  --colors-cyan-800: #155e75;
  --colors-cyan-900: #164e63;
  --colors-sky-50: #f0f9ff;
  --colors-sky-100: #e0f2fe;
  --colors-sky-200: #bae6fd;
  --colors-sky-300: #7dd3fc;
  --colors-sky-400: #38bdf8;
  --colors-sky-500: #0ea5e9;
  --colors-sky-600: #0284c7;
  --colors-sky-700: #0369a1;
  --colors-sky-800: #075985;
  --colors-sky-900: #0c4a6e;
  --colors-blue-50: #ecfdff;
  --colors-blue-100: #d0f7fd;
  --colors-blue-200: #a6ecfb;
  --colors-blue-300: #69ddf7;
  --colors-blue-400: #24c3ec;
  --colors-blue-500: #089ec7;
  --colors-blue-600: #0a85b0;
  --colors-blue-700: #106a8e;
  --colors-blue-800: #165774;
  --colors-blue-900: #174962;
  --colors-indigo-50: #eef2ff;
  --colors-indigo-100: #e0e7ff;
  --colors-indigo-200: #c7d2fe;
  --colors-indigo-300: #a5b4fc;
  --colors-indigo-400: #818cf8;
  --colors-indigo-500: #6366f1;
  --colors-indigo-600: #4f46e5;
  --colors-indigo-700: #4338ca;
  --colors-indigo-800: #3730a3;
  --colors-indigo-900: #312e81;
  --colors-violet-50: #f5f3ff;
  --colors-violet-100: #ede9fe;
  --colors-violet-200: #ddd6fe;
  --colors-violet-300: #c4b5fd;
  --colors-violet-400: #a78bfa;
  --colors-violet-500: #8b5cf6;
  --colors-violet-600: #7c3aed;
  --colors-violet-700: #6d28d9;
  --colors-violet-800: #5b21b6;
  --colors-violet-900: #4c1d95;
  --colors-purple-50: #faf5ff;
  --colors-purple-100: #f3e8ff;
  --colors-purple-200: #e9d5ff;
  --colors-purple-300: #d8b4fe;
  --colors-purple-400: #c084fc;
  --colors-purple-500: #a855f7;
  --colors-purple-600: #9333ea;
  --colors-purple-700: #7e22ce;
  --colors-purple-800: #6b21a8;
  --colors-purple-900: #581c87;
  --colors-fuschia-50: #fdf4ff;
  --colors-fuschia-100: #fae8ff;
  --colors-fuschia-200: #f5d0fe;
  --colors-fuschia-300: #f0abfc;
  --colors-fuschia-400: #e879f9;
  --colors-fuschia-500: #d946ef;
  --colors-fuschia-600: #c026d3;
  --colors-fuschia-700: #a21caf;
  --colors-fuschia-800: #86198f;
  --colors-fuschia-900: #701a75;
  --colors-pink-50: #fdf2f8;
  --colors-pink-100: #fce7f3;
  --colors-pink-200: #fbcfe8;
  --colors-pink-300: #f9a8d4;
  --colors-pink-400: #f472b6;
  --colors-pink-500: #ec4899;
  --colors-pink-600: #db2777;
  --colors-pink-700: #be185d;
  --colors-pink-800: #9d174d;
  --colors-pink-900: #831843;
  --colors-rose-50: #fff1f2;
  --colors-rose-100: #ffe4e6;
  --colors-rose-200: #fecdd3;
  --colors-rose-300: #fda4af;
  --colors-rose-400: #fb7185;
  --colors-rose-500: #f43f5e;
  --colors-rose-600: #e11d48;
  --colors-rose-700: #be123c;
  --colors-rose-800: #9f1239;
  --colors-rose-900: #881337;
  --opacity-0: 0;
  --opacity-5: 0.05;
  --opacity-10: 0.1;
  --opacity-20: 0.2;
  --opacity-25: 0.25;
  --opacity-30: 0.3;
  --opacity-40: 0.4;
  --opacity-50: 0.5;
  --opacity-60: 0.6;
  --opacity-70: 0.7;
  --opacity-75: 0.75;
  --opacity-80: 0.8;
  --opacity-90: 0.9;
  --opacity-95: 0.95;
  --opacity-100: 1;
  ...
}
```

I looked through Tailwind documentation, but I'm not sure how in my case I can add the alpha value to the color that is generated in _variables.css file in hex format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables), you could look at converting your colors to RGB/HSL component value lists:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: 'rgb(var(--colors-default-white) / <alpha-value>)',
      black: 'rgb(var(--colors-default-black) / <alpha-value>)',
      // …
    },
    // …
  },
  // …
};
```

```css
:root {
  --colors-default-white: 255 255 255;
  --colors-default-black: 0 0 0;
  /* … */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="bg-black">
  <div class="w-1/2 h-20 bg-white/25"></div>
</div>

<div class="bg-white">
  <div class="w-1/2 h-20 bg-black/25"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you'd rather not modify the CSS variable values, you could consider using [`color-mix()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) in the Tailwind configuration:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      white: 'color-mix(in srgb, var(--colors-default-white) calc(100% * <alpha-value>), transparent)',
      black: 'color-mix(in srgb, var(--colors-default-black) calc(100% * <alpha-value>), transparent)',
      // …
    },
    // …
  },
  // …
};
```

```css
:root {
  --colors-default-white: #ffffff;
  --colors-default-black: #000000;
  /* … */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="bg-black">
  <div class="w-1/2 h-20 bg-white/25"></div>
</div>

<div class="bg-white">
  <div class="w-1/2 h-20 bg-black/25"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! color-mix() helped me a lot since I don't want to change hex values from CSS variables